# How to close/terminate all resources of my AWS free tier account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had a free tier account which is gonna expire in a couple of days. I just initiated EC2 services for cron jobs which I want to close now. Below are the services running:

[image]

Can you tell me that if I terminate my EC2 instance, will it terminate everything? I do not want to get charges for AWS services

Answer (score 1):

Terminate your instance, check it disappears along with the volume. Delete any snapshots. Next go into the Cost Explorer service to see what else might be costing money - S3, CloudTrail logs, etc.

You can use a tool such as [AWS Nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) to delete everything in your account.

I suspect that deleting your AWS account removes all resources and stops all billing, but I would stop / terminate everything myself to be sure.

Comment: AWS Nuke is not working, I tried to configure it says it could not find region

➜  ~ cloud-nuke inspect-aws         
[cloud-nuke] INFO[2022-06-28T15:06:33+05:00] Identifying enabled regions                  
ERROR: could not find any enabled regions

Comment: Instance terminated, should I remove _Security Groups_ myself?

Comment: Security groups have no cost so no need to remove them. You only care about resources that cost money. Have a look in Cost Explorer. You can also try cloud nuke, and I found this thread which suggests local misconfiguration may be the cause of that error message https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke/issues/102